# No update on initial load of Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

In an RStudio Shiny app what is the best way to have observers start observing AFTER the initial app load. For example, in the app below I want the select inputs to start with initial values of `a` and `1` and then, once the app is loaded, when the user makes a selection from input1 I want input2 changed to "3". But only after the app has loaded -- I want the user to see "1" first.

This is obviously just a very simple example of a more complex app. In my more complex app I set a condition where I compare the value against a global value but there must be an easier way.

```
server<-function(session, input, output) {

  observeEvent(input$input1, {
    updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="3")

  })


}

ui<-fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        selectInput("input1", label="Input1", choices=c("a", "b", "c"), selected="a"),
        selectInput("input2", label="Input2", choices=c("1", "2", "3"), selected="1")
    ),

    mainPanel(

    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but you can add a counter using a reactive value that increases with every change to Input1. On the first change to Input 1 this counter increases to 2 and Input2 is changed to "3". I set the observeEvent to only change Input2 on that first click when rv$X == 2 so Input2 is not always changed to 3 when ever Input1 is modified. See the server fxn below:

```
server<-function(session, input, output) {
   rv<-reactiveValues(X = 1)
   observeEvent(input$input1,{
      if(rv$X==2) updateSelectInput(session, "input2", selected="3")
   rv$X<-rv$X+1
})
```

}

Comment: Thanks. That's a possible solution, but you're right it is not ideal. In my app I already have the equivalent in the form of a global value where I set it on app initialization, then check for equality in the observer and then re-set within the observer. I'm trying to avoid hacks like these if possible.