# ObserveEvent and textInput, confusing behaviour

Tags: r, shiny

Having following simple application:

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('model'),
    textInput('search', 'Look for a model')
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

    options <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

    output$model <- renderUI({
        checkboxGroupInput("model",
                           "Select a model:",
                           options,
                           selected='a')
    })

    observeEvent(input$search,{
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,"model",
                                 "Select a model:",
                                 options[grep(input$search, options)])
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to display choices to the user with `a` already preselected. Later, I would like to update the `CheckboxGroupInput` **only after user starts typing** into a search box . However, the checkbox seems to be updated immediately and the preselected choice `a` is not displayed.

Why does the `observeEvent` does not wait for interaction with the `inputText`? Any ideas how I could fix this and wait until user starts typing (I don't want to use button)?

Comment: Could you please explain the downvote?

Comment: try setting `ignoreInit = TRUE` in the call to `observeEvent`.

Comment: That is what I posted in my answer, but thank you for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Prevent execution of observe on app load in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165567/prevent-execution-of-observe-on-app-load-in-shiny) provides the answer. The `observeEvent` will just not be executed on start.

**EDIT:** (to make answer explicit as @lbusett suggested)

Setting `ignoreInit = TRUE` in the call to `observeEvent` solves the problem.